# issue with react-router showing component when not in route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router and having some difficulties with it's behaviour.

The `Nav` shows on all pages as desired. However, the `Profile` shows on all pages too. I only want to show this on `/home` and also on the `/music` and `/players` pages, which it does. However, it also shows on the `/charts` page which is confusing me.

My code looks like the following.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Nav from './components/Nav'
import Profile from './components/Profile'
import Players from './components/Players'
import Music from './components/Music'
import Charts from './components/Charts'

const App = () => {

  return (
    <section>

      <Nav />

      <Route path="/home">
        <div>
          <Profile avatarUrl={ avatarUrl }/>
          <Route path="/players" component={Players}/>
          <Route path="/music" component={Music}/>
        </div>
      </Route>

      <Route path="/charts" component={Charts}/>

    </section>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I have read through the docs, tried putting in a `Switch` component, added `exact` to the `home` route but this leads to other unexpected behaviour.

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

Thanks Pete!

Comment: Hey Pete! Why have you placed `players` and `music` routes inside `home`? Do you wish to render `Players` and `Music` when the `Home` route is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

import Nav from './components/Nav'
import Profile from './components/Profile'
import Players from './components/Players'
import Music from './components/Music'
import Charts from './components/Charts'

const Home = ({match}) => {
    return (
    <div>
      <Profile avatarUrl={ avatarUrl }/>
      <Route path=`${match.url}/players` component={Players}/>
      <Route path=`${match.url}/music` component={Music}/>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {

  return (
    <section>

      <Nav />
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/charts" exact={true} component={Charts}/>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>

    </section>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I haven't tested this, but this should work.

Assuming that you're using react-router v4, I don't know if you can actually use your home route in the way you've used it.

In the code above, Switch basically renders the first match between the routes specified under it. The exact keyword will ensure that only `/charts` path will display the `Charts` component.

The `Home` component will render in any path that starts with `/home`.
Now, for path `/home/players`, you'll see the `Profile` and the `Players` component, whereas for path `/home/music`, you'll see the other combination.

Hope this helps. :)

**Edit:**
Added `Router` to the code.

**Edit:**
Working code available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/8x9pql9m19
Change route on right hand side to:
`/home`
`/home/players`
`/home/music`
`/charts`

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined` doesn't know what `match` is

Comment: You're including `App` inside a `Router` somewhere, right?

Comment: it still doesn't really make sense why my Profile route is showing in the `Charts`component does it?

Comment: Can you try adding the `Router` element? I've added it to the sample code.

Comment: I'm not sure why Profile route is getting rendered, but react-router v4 does not support nested routes like you've used in your original code.

Comment: maybe I need to rewrite it completely, as there is still issues with match even with updated code :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166588/discussion-between-peter-flanagan-and-shishir).